# WP_Query by cat where cat comes from $_GET[] returns all post

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I am trying to get all post of a cetegory throught a WP_Query:

```
//url whould be www.blablabla.com/?cat=4
$featured = new WP_Query('cat=$_GET["cat"]');
```

where cat is the Http GET param. This retuns all the post ignoring the "cat" parameter. But if I write an integer value instead of the $_GET I get the expected post, ie:

```
//This returns all the post of the category with slug = 4
$featured = new WP_Query('cat=4');
```

If I write $_GET["cat"] before then a 4 appears on screen. I supposse That WP_Query is getting the param as string and this is making the condition to be ignored, but I have try to cast in anyway the param but I can't get it to work.
I am new to Wordpress so I am sure this is pretty much stupid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. `echo 'cat=$_GET["cat"]';`, 2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$featured = new WP_Query('cat='.$_GET["cat"]);
```

The parameter you're passing to WP_Query is a single-quoted string. No variable interpolation is done on single-quoted strings, so you're actually passing the literal string cat=$_GET["cat"], when you want to pass cat=4

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $_GET["cat"] is giving you the expected value?

try:
$cat = $_GET["cat"];//You should add validation here
var_dump($cat);//just to check to see that the right value is there, remove this line when done
$featured = new WP_Query("cat=$cat");